# How to fix error Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I get a warning saying:
"Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'" for the student variable.  I am copying/pasting the code out of a book into xcode and am not sure how to fix this.  The only thing that prints in the console is "(lldb)".  Any advice

```
#include <stdio.h>

void congratulateStudent(char student, char course, int numDays)
{
    printf("%s has done as much %s Programming as I could fit into %d days.\n", student, course, numDays);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // insert code here...
    congratulateStudent("mark", "Cocoa", 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
void congratulateStudent(char *student, char *course, int numDays)
```

the `%s` means that you are going to print a string ( array of chars)

and `char student` this means that student is a `char` type

so student here is not a pointer to a string

In order to change the student type from char to a string pointer you have to add asterisk to student `char *student`

In your code you are calling the `congratulateStudent` with input parameter string `"mark"`. So to support this string the input parameter `student` should be defined as pointer of string

so you are missing the asterisk in the definition of student

The same thing for `course`

Answer (score 1):

`void congratulateStudent(char *student, char *course, int numDays)`

Use Function signature like because you are passing string as argument to function in `main` but function has character type argument..