# Conflicting types issue

Tags: c

I am following [the book](http://www.bignerdranch.com/we-write/objective-c-programming.html) to create a simple C program, the following code is from the book :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    congratulateStudent("Kate", "Cocoa", 5);

    return 0;
}

void congratulateStudent(char *student, char *course, int numDays) {
    printf("%s has done as much %s Programming as I could fit into %d days.\n",
           student, course, numDays);
}
```

After I copy & paste the above code to my XCode, I got error:

```
Conflicting types for 'congratulateStudent'
```

I noticed there is another person has the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039329/how-to-fix-error-format-specifies-type-char-but-the-argument-has-type-char) with the book's code , I tried the accepted answer, changed the code to :

```
void congratulateStudent(char *student, char *course, int numDays) {
        printf("%s has done as much %s Programming as I could fit into %d days.\n",
               *student, *course, numDays);
    }
```

But the compiler error is still there, what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a function declaration before `main`:

```
void congratulateStudent(char *student, char *course, int numDays);
```

UPDATE 1: You can alternatively move the `congratulateStudent` function before `main`.

UPDATE 2: The answer that you refer to in the link, focuses on that the user uses wrong argument types in the function than those he/she intends to use in: `char, char, int` and that `%s, %s, %d` used in `printf` work for `char*, char*, int` types, so this is something different.

Comment: Or move the congratulateStudent function at the top before main

Comment: **Above** being the important part. In C methods have to be declared before they are used.

Comment: So, the other person's accepted answer which I have linked in my post is not correct ? right? Does that answer make any sense?

Comment: @Nick, I still want to know does the other answer in my link make any sense, since it also suggested to add asterisk before student & course when passing the parameter to the function insdie main.

Comment: In the other answer, he had placed the user defined function before main. So it was correct. He was having problem with `char` and `char *`.

Comment: @user842225 , Read it more carefully. The answer told to change the function signature and not anything in the `printf`

Comment: Answer updated again. In that link, the user mentions something else.
Please suggest me for further improvements and do not forget to vote it as best answer, if it deserves it.

Answer (score 3):

It's because in your main function, the `congratulateStudent` function was not declared yet, and the compiler assumes it returns `int` by default, then you define it below to return `void`, hence the

```
Conflicting types for 'congratulateStudent'
```

so either declare the function before `main` or move it's definition before `main`, both solutions work.

Comment: If you disable warnings, it might compile and even work, but this is the reason.

Comment: @Gopi Read up on Implicit declaration

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void congratulateStudent(char *student, char *course, int numDays) {
   printf("%s has done as much %s Programming as I could fit into %d days.\n",
       student, course, numDays);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

congratulateStudent("Kate", "Cocoa", 5);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your compiler's warning flags are set: `-Wall -Wextra`.  Those should have given you a warning that the compiler didn't understand the function `congratulateStudent` within `main`.  My compiler gave me the output

```
line 6: warning: implicit declaration of function `congratulateStudent'
```

These sorts of warnings can help you figure out where your mistakes are.

And, to fix both the warning and the error, we can add a function prototype near the top of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void congratulateStudent(char *student, char *course, int numDays);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
...
```